# Why did my suggested edit get rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Can anyone explain why [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1860383) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828283/encryption-on-alphanumeric) was rejected?

The person originally asking the question confused encryption and compression, and in the comments he stated that he is actually looking for compression rather than encryption, I mentioned this fact in the comment accompanying the edit.

Since the question might actually become very interesting, I though it would be helpful to correct the question for the OP and fix the grammar in the process.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. The reviewers should have approved, in my opinion. It is a good edit.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I do? Suggest the edit again?

Comment: @Null: you can try that or one of us could simply do the edit you tried (but you won't get the rep from that). But then again: this is almost certainly a duplicate of about a dozen other questions ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer I can forego the two rep points. If you could just make the edit I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @NULL: I submitted your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your suggestion, it was valid. The reviewers were wrong in not approving it.

You did well in posting it here. In the meanwhile, your edit was submitted by a different user.

Comment: Yeah, Joachim Sauer offered to make the change for me.

Answer (score 4):

Although your edit was indeed perfectly valid, and turned an objectively absurd question into a valid one, I, for one, understand the reasoning behind the rejection.

The OP clearly doesn't know the first thing about encryption and/or compression. Somebody taking the time to point out the differences between the two might be more helpful to the OP, and the SO community.
If I were confronted with your edit however, I would have approved it, because the original format will lead to tons of down-votes, discussions in comments, and irritation... so that *"ideal answer"* I mentioned earlier will never be posted anyway.

In the end, it is quite subjective... I have rejected valid edits because they actually answered (part of) the original question, or corrected an error in the code that could have been a typo, but could just as well have been the problem itself...

Bottom line: your edit *was* valid, but sometimes a valid edit might reduce the chance of fetching a great answer. *though it is my personal opinion that this is not the case here*

Comment: I see what you mean, but in the comments the OP already agreed that compression is the better term.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I couldn't agree more, really. But thanks to the comments, at least we're sure the OP understands the edit, and has a better of things