# Should a suggested edit to remove a link to a deleted post be approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

I got this [suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3541103) which basically removes the link to a deleted post. (the edit is now approved, I skipped it)

Reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175298/clear-rules-on-reviewing-edits?lq=1) question and it's answers doesn't say anything on how to handle this case.

What is the general rule for editing-out links to deleted posts?
What repsonse should be given when presented with such an edit when reviewing?

(bonus chatter: is there maybe a per-site difference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of meta sites, it will be rare for users to need to link to a deleted question. Such questions hold no value to the community - that's why they are deleted.

In the [specific case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175298/clear-rules-on-reviewing-edits?lq=1) you refer to, the overall succinctness of the question is improved by removing the link to the deleted question. It adds no value to the question and probably serves to pre-dispose readers to look for problems with this question.

I don't think there is a general rule that can be applied in all cases. Treat each suggested edit on its own merits. But again, I'd be surprised to find such a link being useful outside of a meta site.

Typically when such questions are linked to from meta, users add a *"(10k only)*" suffix to the link to indicate it's not visible to everyone.

Comment: "it will be rare for users to need to link to a deleted question": that's a good point, +1

Comment: A good, and somewhat understated point ;) /cc @Bathsheba

Answer (score 3):

Remember the Stack Overflow philosophy (applicable, I think, to all Stack Exchange sites):

According to the Stack Overflow [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Therefore we don't want any broken links. A link to a deleted question is broken as very few users can navigate to them. Therefore an acceptable edit and worth the +2 rep to an entitled editor. That said though, I'd be dismayed to learn of a user who has acquired 1,000 points by fixing broken links. So do judge each edit request in turn.

Comment: I do understand and not at all disagree with the sentiment you express about editors choosing some 'simple' type of edit to just power through the 1000 reputation. That said, if someone did 500 *useful* edits removing broken links, I would be perfectly happy with that. People tend to have pet peeves, and if those peeves are to fix things which need fixing (and they aren't leaving other glaring issues unfixed), I say more power to them!

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn Yes I think you're correct. 500 broken links fixed is a good thing.

Comment: Yup! <annoyance>That said, I really do dislike when people go through doing simple 'peeve' edits for the +2, while leaving glaring problems otherwise.</annoyance>